# How to fix 'A callback parameter was not provided in the request URI.' error in ajax post method and asp.net api using cross domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain

I'm trying to implement a page using ajax POST, PUT and delete method with cross domain. I'm getting an issue with returning response message to client from the server.

if the controller return httpStausCode without any additional message no error appeared but with some additional message I'm getting an error in server side 'A callback parameter was not provided in the request URI.'

Request code

```js
$("#myTable").on('click', '.deleteCandidate', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: 'http://localhost:59838/api/candidate/' + $(this).data("id"),
                content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                    console.log(xhr.statusText);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
```

Server Code

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MutliTiersDataBaseEntities entities = new MutliTiersDataBaseEntities())
                {
                    var entity = entities.Candidates.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);

                    if (entity != null)
                    {
                        entities.Candidates.Remove(entity);
                        entities.SaveChanges();
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Candidate with id = "+ id.ToString() +" has been deleted");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Candidate with Id:" + id.ToString() + " not exist");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);

            }
        }
```

I'm expect the output is status code 200, message Candidate with id = xx has been deleted but I'm getting an error with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way to go with enabling cross domain not with jsonp

for more details: [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)